# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation.MyActivity

Tags: java, android, crash, crash-reports, runtimeexception

I have a basic app(guide for an Indian exam) on the play store which displays some information in various activities.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation

And I am getting this crash report on play store but I'm unable to see why this is caused

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
```

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation/com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation.MyActivity}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  "com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.akshitrewari.gateexampreparation-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
... 11 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:326)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
... 8 more
```

The device is "A1+ Super" and android version is 4.4

Please help me find the cause of the crash so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61916

Basically an issue with certain apps the ART and Android 4.4

No solution.

Steve.